# How to import GEBCO bathymetry into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import, bathymetry

I'm experiencing problems with the import of bathymetry data in QGIS, which I downloaded freely from GEBCO or NOAA. The problem is that if I import the grid (either with .nc or .asc extension, or if I extract it as geotiff), I simply get a grey map with very faint or no differentiation in depth.

Does anybody know what the problem is? Are there are other free sources to get bathymetry data from?

Thanks!

ellen

Comment: I am new to QGIS and loaded Global Muti-Resolution Topography WMS data from http://www.marine-geo.org/services/wms_2.0_merc?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.0.0 I am stilt trying to dispay the bathymetry, ideally in the status bar along side the coordinates. This is readily available in GeoMapApp. The latter has less features than QGIS but is easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using 1.8 or earlier?  If so, you'll need to set each Raster layer's display.  On the style tab of the layer's properties make sure the Contrast Enhancement is set.  For example when I load DEMs I use Stretch to Min / Max.

Comment: Excellent!  If you want to have that done automatically, go to Settings -> Options and on the Rendering tab you can pick which settings gets used by default when you load in a raster.